# How can I force my Azure AD app to read new claims?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an app that has various App Roles mapped to AD Groups. When I add a user to one of the groups, their claims don't appear to update, and the membership in the group doesn't give them the access they need.

How can I force the app to read the current claims based on updated AD Group membership?

Comment: You should probably be calling the AAD Graph API directly to get this information. See [here](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/clients-tokens-claims-oh-my/). That being said, the claims in the token should never be "stale" as long as they are correctly being updated in the directory, and you are acquiring a new token. Can you show evidence of the claims not updating?

Comment: @JonCrowell don't delete! Answer your own question, I bet there's dozens of others who've had this same question.

Comment: Claims are not dynamic. You have to logout / login to get the updated versions.